# How to retrieve id of just inserted firestore document (with angularfire2)?

Tags: angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm inserting a new document into my firestore collection like so:

```
this.afs.collection<Client>('clients').add(this.form.value).then(docRef => {
  console.log("Need to output the firestore generated doc id of the document here: ...")
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it: then() takes a **union type** (http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html): `void | DocumentReference`.

Therefore needs to be addressed like this:

```
this.afs.collection<Client>('clients').add(this.form.value).then(docRef => {
  console.log((docRef) ? (<DocumentReference>docRef).id : 'void') // docRef of type void | DocumentReference
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
this.afs.collection<Client>('clients').add(this.form.value).then(docRef => {
  console.log(docRef.id);
})
```

Comment: This yields a compile error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'void | DocumentReference'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a key by yourself.

```
...
this.generatedKey = this.generateNewKey('clients');
...

this.afs.collection<Client>(`clients`).doc(this.generatedKey)
  .set({ someField: 'some value' })
  .then(docRef => {
    console.log("Self generated doc ID: ...", this.generatedKey )
})

generateNewKey(ref: any) {
  const _ref = firebase.firestore().collection(ref).doc();
  const newKey = _ref.id;
  return newKey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer the OP.