# How to get newly created auto generated ID from angularfire2 cloud firestore

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

I am trying to get the auto generated ID from firestore after it have been freshly created but I don't know why when I `console.log(ref)`, it is `undefined`, please have a look at my codes:

```js
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {

  usersCollectionRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersCollectionRef = this.firestore.collection<any>('users');
  }

  addUpdateContact(name: string, email: string) {
    const newId = this.firestore.createId();
    this.usersCollectionRef.doc(newId).set({ username: name, email: email }).then(ref => {
      console.log(ref);
    });
  }
}
```

It manages to successfully insert data into firestore though

I am using `ionic 3` and `angularfire2` 5.4.2

I have tried solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49729125) but it does not work... Please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, for anyone in the future who needs the solution:

Change the `addUpdateContact` codes to:

```js
this.usersCollectionRef.add({ username: name, email: email }).then(ref => {
      console.log(ref.id);
    });
```

Thanks to @nikoswsn for giving me an idea to google for [this](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/getting-started-firestore-angularfire2/), the `1. Saving Data` part is about the same code as what I modified

Answer (score 0):

With .set() method you have to specify the document ID, thus it means you already have the ID. Please clarify what you are looking forward to achieve.

Please also check the returning object of .set() method [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set)

Comment: I am trying to get the ID that was auto generated by firebase after executing ``addUpdateContact``, ``console.log(ref.id)`` gives error: ``Property 'id' does not exist on type 'void'.``

Comment: Thank you sir, you gave me the idea to google the correct keyword... I will update with a answer