# How can I get the id of a document created with .add() in AngularFire Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have this code

```
 this.angularFirestore.collection<Loja>("lojas").add(loja)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
     });
```

I need to get the document ID of the recent create document. I can't get it from the data variable...

Comment: Here is a solution. You need to check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49740038/10659482

Comment: The answer is so simple... I felt dumb right now. Being noob sux. XD thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to separate the creation of the document ID from the writing of the document:

```
const id = this. angularFirestore.createId();
this.angularFirestore.collection<Loja>("lojas").doc(id).set(loja)
```

Also see:

- the AngularFire documentation on [storing the document ID](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#example-of-persisting-a-document-id)